# Mixing audio to mono - changing display name of remap

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, udev

Following the post "Can I downmix stereo audio to mono" I can remap my headphone amp output to mono (I'm deaf in one ear).

However the device name that appears in the displayable selection list of audio devices is "Remapped CM6631A Audio Processor Analogue Stereo"

It would be so much nicer to have this displayed as "SMSL M6 Mono" . I haven't done so yet but I believe I can set the name of the unmapped device (which currently appears as "Speakers CM6631A Audio Processor") to something more meaningful via a UDEV rule but how do I do similar with its remap?